# Substitute Toolbar with Collapsing Toolbar in different Fragment

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I might be missing something very simple here, but I could definitely use some help.

I have an activity inside which I want to load different fragments with different content and different toolbar style (i.e. Toolbars with custom View and CollapsingToolbarLayout(that too having custom layout inside in it)). At the same time, I want to have one instance of the drawer, accessible through the single activity(i.e. MainActivity).

I have gone through the examples to find something similar, but all of them use new activities in order to populate their content or they just hide/show toolbar content that is not appropriate in my case as I've custom Toolbar views for each Fragment, therefore I cannot find out what should be the order of the layout views. Some of the solution that I've gone through are like :

1. [Collapsing Toolbar only for one Fragment in Navigation View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44721554/collapsing-toolbar-only-for-one-fragment-in-navigation-view)
2. [Coordinator Layout with Toolbar in Fragments or Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30739806/coordinator-layout-with-toolbar-in-fragments-or-activity)
3. [Collapsing Toolbar and DrawerLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38501079/collapsing-toolbar-and-drawerlayout)

**TL;DR**

For one Fragment I want Toolbar as below

[image]

And for other Fragment

[image]

Comment: if you want single activity and replace the whole content inside including Toolbar , in each fragment you can set your toolbar inside fragment (toolbar not in activity). When you click icon menu (top left) in each fragment, just call show navigation menu of Activity

Comment: _I want to have one instance of the drawer, accessible through the single activity_ without toolbar in MainActivity We wont able to show drawer Icon.

Comment: Yup, you set the menu drawer in your MainActivity. You set toolbar for each fragment (each fragment still has drawer icon), when click drawer icon, just call show navigation drawer from MainActivity

Comment: Are you able to show me any samples / link for solution ? I don't get you at all.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

This is not a clean code but it is a working one. I just want to show you. You can use something like BaseFragment and structure a better code. In MainFragment you can use navigation drawer and in DetailFragment you can use back arrow on toolbar. If you want you can use navigation view in DetailFragment too. Also you can use collapsing toolbar in any fragment which you prefer.

MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var actionBarToggle : ActionBarDrawerToggle? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setUpNavigationList()
        if (savedInstanceState == null){
            supportFragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, MainFragment())
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit()
        }
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
        when(item!!.itemId){
            android.R.id.home -> onBackPressed()
        }
        return true
    }

    fun setActionBarDrawerToggle(toolbar: Toolbar){
        actionBarToggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer_layout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close)
        actionBarToggle?.syncState()
        drawer_layout.closeDrawer(Gravity.START)
    }

    fun lockDrawer(lock: Boolean){
        val lockMode = if (lock) DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED else DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED
        drawer_layout.setDrawerLockMode(lockMode)
        actionBarToggle?.isDrawerIndicatorEnabled = lock
    }

    private fun setUpNavigationList(){
        val items = arrayListOf("Detail Fragment")
        val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items)
        list_navigation.adapter = adapter
        list_navigation.setOnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->
            when (position){
                0 -> {
                    supportFragmentManager
                            .beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.frame_container, DetailFragment())
                            .addToBackStack(null)
                            .commit()
                }
            }
            drawer_layout.closeDrawer(Gravity.START)
        }

    }


}
```

MainFragment

```
class MainFragment() : Fragment() {


    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false)
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        (activity as AppCompatActivity).setSupportActionBar(toolbar_detail)
        (activity as MainActivity).lockDrawer(false)
        (activity as MainActivity).setActionBarDrawerToggle(toolbar_main)
    }


}
```

DetailFragment

```
class DetailFragment() : Fragment() {


    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false)
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        (activity as MainActivity).setSupportActionBar(toolbar_detail)
        (activity as MainActivity).lockDrawer(true)
        (activity as MainActivity).supportActionBar!!.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

    }

}
```

Main Activity Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.coskun.drawer.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_navigation"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_gravity="start"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

MainFragment Layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.coskun.drawer.DetailFragment">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/main_fragment"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

DetailFragment Layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.coskun.drawer.DetailFragment">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_detail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/detail_fragment"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

PREVIOUS ANSWER:

```
You can define navigation drawer logic in activity and you can use separate toolbars for each fragment. You just need to sync state navigation drawer state with fragment toolbars. 

    fun setActionBarDrawerToggle(toolbar: Toolbar){
            actionBarToggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close)
            actionBarToggle?.syncState()
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.START)
        }

    fun lockDrawer(lock: Boolean){
        val lockMode = if (lock) DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED else DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED
        drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(lockMode)
        actionBarToggle?.isDrawerIndicatorEnabled = lock
    }
```

You can take a look at this code. I set toolbar as action bar in every fragment and let them to inflate their own menu and sync with activities drawer state. Let me know if this helps.